# How to generate a travel map?

Tags: maps, travel-tools

For various reasons I have to present ~100 pictures of my last trip through Europe. To make this presentation more informative, I'd like to include an animated travel map that shows the route I traveled. It should be possible to enter various destinations and then link them in arbitrary order. Additionally, I'd like to specify if I used a plane, train, ferry, bus or car.

Are there any free tools available that have these features?

Comment: Did you eventually use the suggestions? Good experience with it?

Comment: iMovie now has this feature.

Comment: @Bradman175 do you have a link with a description? I tried to do it, but couldn't

Comment: @RoflcoptrException https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14706?locale=en_AU&viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[TravellersPoint](https://www.travellerspoint.com/travel-maps.cfm) has a great map making feature.

[Google MyMaps](https://maps.google.com) or [Google Earth](https://earth.google.com) could also be good tools for creating a map. Google Earth in particular now supports "[Tours](https://www.google.com/earth/outreach/tutorials/kmltours.html)" that you can record to show an animated path, even with narration and photos.

Answer (score 12):

I used [Tripline](http://www.tripline.net/) to show where I've been on recent trips. Again it's point A to B, but at least you can easily share it on Facebook or a Blog. For example, my 2010 [South American journey map](http://www.marksmayo.com/south-american-journey/) is embedded on my blog.

They are in beta and seem to be adding new features fairly recently. I'd love them to add the ability to show two people travelling at once - like if you were racing someone across Europe, showing where you each were at diff times on the same map would look awesome.

Comment: Thanks. That has everything I need expect for the ability to choose between plane, cars, ferries, etc.

Comment: Nice, but still allows for Gowalla and not for Flickr. Odd.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [globtrottr.com](http://globtrottr.com) that is a nice little website that allows to create journeys using different transport types, display them on a map and calculate stats.